# Trying to create a numpy array and failing

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I am trying to run a code that was regularly working, but now I get an error

The first lines of my code are:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([0,1,2])
```

Then, I get the following error:

> 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Works fine for me... I copy-pasted your script

Comment: Can you confirm that your `array = np.array([0,1,2])` code is the line responsible for the error? Could you provide the whole error?  If you have follow-on code, read the traceback for the line numbers.  I can bet your error is for another line.

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis I tested just this line on a new cell and still getting the same error

Comment: what numpy version you are using. np.__version__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine in Jupyter notebook. You might want to restart your session and try again. An other alternative would be to use a different name to assign the array object instead of 'array' itself.

Comment: thanks, just restarted my runtime at my colab notebook and solved the problem